# Show item in QuickBooks Desktop programmatically

Tags: quickbooks

My website allows users to enter QuickBooks item numbers like purchase order numbers. I'd like to make those a link so that clicking on them pops up the item in their QuickBooks desktop software. It doesn't seem like QuickBooks Web Connector can do this. The QuickBooks API also doesn't mention anything like this. What about writing a plug-in for QuickBooks? Or does QuickBooks respond to a custom URL scheme? To be clear, I'm not trying to exchange any data. I'm only trying to take them straight to a particular item (such as a purchase order) in their desktop version of QuickBooks given the number of that item. I'm willing to write Windows code to make this happen.